# I want to find a spectral decomposition of the matrix $B$ given the following information.

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the spectral decomposition of the of the matrix $B$ given the following information:

A =\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\ 
1 & 2\\ 
\end{pmatrix}

with $c \gt 0$ and $B = cA$.

I found that for $A$ the eigenvalues are as follows: $\lambda_1 = 3, \lambda_2 = 1$. Furthermore, after normalizing, the corresponding eigenvectors are

$$\bf{v_1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$\bf{v_2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I know that $A$ is a symmetric matrix, so $cA = B$ should also be symmetric. Thus, I should be able to use these 2 eigenpairs to give a spectral decomposition for $B$.

Comment: Of course, I found the eigenpairs for $A$, not $B$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  eigenvectors you found (or just common sense) to deduce that the spectral decomposition of $A$ is
$$
A=3\,\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}+1\,\begin{bmatrix}1/2&-1/2\\-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So
$$
B=3c\,\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}+c\,\begin{bmatrix}1/2&-1/2\\-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: So, maybe something I should be taking away from this problem is that if $B$ is just $A$ multiplied by a scalar-- in this case $c$-- then that scalar basically just gets absorbed into the eigenvalues when we do the spectral decomposition?

Comment: Yes. If you multiply a matrix by a scalar the eigenvalues will get multiplied by that scalar, and the eigenspaces will not change.